# AngularJS - Bindings Timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following simple setup:

A controller, which is calling a service to get the list of categories:

```
$scope.enquiryCategories = CategoryServices.listCategories();
```

A service, which fetches the data from the external API:

```
listCategories: function () {
  return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/some_external_api/categories.json'}).then(function (result) {
    return result.data.custom_field_options;
  });
}
```

In the view, I just ng-repeat over the enquiryCategories.

It works, however in some cases it does not display the list on the first load, forcing the user to refresh the page.  It's like I have some kind of a timing issue, but I'm lost to what can cause it.

I've tried implementing listCategories to return a promise object, but it still suffers from the same issue.

I'm using AngularJS 1.0.8.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.then()` in the controller as well to resolve it completely:

```
CategoryServices.listCategories().then(function(data) {
    $scope.enquiryCategories = data;
});
```